# Dlink dir 685 with static IP. Cannot see router from other network

Tags: networking, router, isp, static-ip

I have l2tp connection.
My ISP gave me static IP.
I can ping this IP from my ISP network successfully.
But if I ping it from other ISP - it doesn't.

I have dlink 685 router.
Unchecked in Firewall Settings "Enable SPI".

So what are the other settings could be there to make work it?

Comment: What is the static IP which you have? Is it a normal IP or a private on from the RFC1918 range?